# Android, ListView showing identical data from ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

The following code:

```
    int i = 0;
    for(Shift shift : mShifts){
        shifts[i] = shift + "";
        i++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shifts);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

produces a list of all unique *Shift objects* - something that looks like...

```
com.name.appname.Shift@529a4ecc
com.name.appname.Shift@529a5010
com.name.appname.Shift@529a5088
com.name.appname.Shift@529a5100
... ect ...
```

for as many Shift objects I have created. Where `mShifts` is an ArrayList of *Shift* objects.

But, when I use the following:

```
    int i = 0;
    for(Shift shift : mShifts){
        shifts[i] = String.format("%d", shift.getEnd());
        i++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shifts);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

it produces a list of **all identical values**, when they are verified to be unique. The only change is in the string assignment within the loop.

The identical values are all the time stamp from the most recent Shift object.

`shift.getEnd()` produces a long value, which is a time stamp (milliseconds) from when an event occurred. Each value is stored in a database, and I have verified (using SQLite Database Browser) that all entries are truly unique.

**EDIT 1**

I assign `mShifts` from the DB in the following way:

```
    ArrayList<Shift> mShifts = new ArrayList<Shift>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int i = 0;
        do{
            Shift shift = new Shift(getStringFromColumnName(cursor, ShiftsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SHIFT_NAME),
                    getStringFromColumnName(cursor, ShiftsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SHIFT_EMPLOYER),
                    getLongFromColumnName(cursor, ShiftsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SHIFT_START),
                    i);

            mShifts.add(shift);
            i++;
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

It is important to note that I have hard-coded the value for `end` with the variable `i` above - that way I know for certain that it is not an error reading from the DB. There are 12 objects, for whatever reason the printout in the array list shows all having `end=11` (the value of the last object).

The issue is not with assigning the ArrayList, but rather displaying it.

**Edit 2**

Viewing the `mShifts` arrayList in the debugger (while assigning the list) shows that on each loop ALL the values in the array list are set to the most recent one.

So the offending code is the assignment loop.

**Shift class**

```
public class Shift {
    private static String mName;
    private static String mEm;
    private static long mStart;
    private static long mEnd;

    public Shift(String name, String em, long start, long end) {
        setName(name);
        setEm(em);
        setStart(start);
        setEnd(end);
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
    public static void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public static String getEm() {
        return mEm;
    }
    public static void setEm(String em) {
        mEm = em;
    }

    public static long getStart() {
        return mStart;
    }
    public static void setStart(long start) {
        mStart = start;
    }

    public static long getEnd() {
        return mEnd;
    }
    public static void setEnd(long end) {
        mEnd = end;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other code snippets.

Comment: Can you output the result of  String.format("%d", shift.getEnd()); in your loop alors with the result of shift.getEnd() to see how they compare?

Comment: Identical. I even hardcoded the values for `end` with unique numbers, but still all only show the value for the last object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static variable is a class attribute not an object attribute, any code referring to the variable is referring to the exact same data.

In your case your overwriting the previous content of Shift attributes.

Comment: Nope. Still only shows the data from the most recent (last) object.

Comment: The values appearing are all correct, but they only belong to the last object in the arrayList

Comment: Looking at `mShifts` in the debugger shows all identical objects. Code for setting the objects is above in original question.

Comment: Why all attributes and methods in Shift class are static

Comment: I think that it's coming from there.

Comment: You don't need static "things", remove them and give it a try.

Comment: @issathing that's the solution - worked like a charm! Please make answer